# Python Dataframe Groupby function not producing expected output

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by

I have been struggling with this for several days, this is my last resort.

Here is an example of my data

```
| PRODUCT NAME   | PRICE | LINK      | INSTOCK | TAGS   |
|----------------|-------|-----------|---------|--------|
| the best shirt | 1.00  | www.alink | true    | cotton |
| the best shirt | 1.00  | www.alink | true    | yellow |
| the best pants | 2.00  | www.alink | true    | denim  |
```

and here is what I would like

```
| PRODUCT NAME   | PRICE | LINK      | INSTOCK | TAGS           |
|----------------|-------|-----------|---------|----------------|
| the best shirt | 1.00  | www.alink | true    | cotton, yellow |
| the best pants | 2.00  | www.alink | true    | denim          |
```

this is the code I am using

```
df = df.groupby(['PRODUCT NAME', 'PRICE', 'LINK', 'INSTOCK'])[['TAGS']].apply(', '.join)
```

and this is what I get

```
| 0    |
|------|
| TAGS |
```

I am completely at a loss of what could be causing this. Thanks in advance <3

Comment: Instead of `apply` try `.agg(', '.join)`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the output, I would assume your problem stems from having NaNs in your data .

Referring to your example, for me this approach works:

```
products = {'PRODUCT NAME': ['the best shirt', 'the best shirt', 'the best pants'],
            'PRICE': [1.00, 1.00, 2.00],
            'LINK': ['link', 'link', 'link'],
            'INSTOCK': [True, True, True],
            'TAGS': ['cotton', 'yellow', 'denim']}
df = pd.DataFrame(products)
df = df.groupby(['PRODUCT NAME','PRICE','LINK','INSTOCK']).TAGS.apply(lambda x: ', '.join(x)).reset_index()
df
```

Your result

Comment: This kinda works... but it removes all the rows that do not have duplicates. Are you getting the same result? Also, would you have any suggestions if there were more than one column that needed to be joined (like a second tags column)?

Comment: not sure what you mean by "it removes all the rows that do not have duplicates". So all i can say: For the mentioned example, I am getting the desired output. With regard to your second question: `df.groupby(['PRODUCT NAME', 'PRICE', 'LINK', 'INSTOCK']).agg({'TAGS': my_function, 'TAGS2': my_function}).reset_index()` works for me (in combination with `def my_function(x): return ', '.join(x)`, of course)